# Ignoring 1 after getting 2s compliment of 000 in 3 variable truth table

Tags: binary, logic, physics, digital

I had an exam in DLD subject. There was a question as "Design a circuit which can take 2’s compliment of any 3 bit number".
The truth table we get is :

```
A| B| C|
0| 0| 0|
0| 0| 1|
0| 1| 0|
0| 1| 1|
1| 0| 0|
1| 0| 1|
1| 1| 0|
1| 1| 1|
```

Whereas when we find 2s complement as

```
000
111
 +1
----
1000
```

But I have watched many videos where they have ignored 1 and wrote the answer in 3 bits
as

```
A|B|C
0|0|0
```

Iam much confusing why they ignored 1 and what is the problem if we put 1 rather than ignoring

Comment: Where does the `1` go? If you have `n` bits of space to store a number, and you overflow, where does the extra `1` go?

Comment: I think that in order to make it 3 bit,1 is ignored ? probably.